# GDB execute next instruction after watchpoint is hit

Tags: c, gdb

I have a function of the following form:

```
void foo(){
    int *a = //...
    *a = 1;
    //some actions
    *a = 2;
    //some actions
    *a = 3;
    //some actions
    //etc...
}
```

I want to set a watchpoint on `a`, execute next instruction with `si`, print registers and then continue until the watchpoint of `a` is hit again and repeat that.

I wrote the following script:

```
b foo
watch *a
commands
    si
    info reg
    cont
end
cont
```

The problem is it stops after the first watchpoint is hit and neither prints registers and nor continues execution. As I read in [docs](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Break-Commands.html)

> Any other commands in the command list, after a command that resumes
>   execution, are ignored. This is because any time you resume execution
>   (even with a simple next or step), you may encounter another
>   breakpoint—which could have its own command list, leading to
>   ambiguities about which list to execute.

everything after `si` is simply ignored.

Is there a way to write such a script (`gdb` or `python`)?

Answer (score 2):

Before `watch *a` you may run the program via `run`.

If not you'll get something like this: `No symbol "a" in current context.`

So try this:

```
b foo
run
watch *a
commands
    si
    info reg
    cont
end
cont
```